# ElementTree find returns None even without xmlns

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree, nonetype

I am trying to replace some values in XML using ElementsTree without xmlns in Python 2.7.5 but it always returns None, no matter what.

Here is my truncated.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definition>
    <scm>
        <configVersion>2</configVersion>
        <userRemoteConfigs>
            <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
                <url>git@github.company.com:org/repository.git</url>
                <credentialsId>abcdefgh-123456-7890</credentialsId>
            </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        </userRemoteConfigs>
        <branches>
            <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
                <name>refs/heads/master</name>
            </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        </branches>
        <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
        <submoduleCfg/>
        <extensions/>
    </scm>
    <scriptPath>Jenkinsfile</scriptPath>
    <lightweight>true</lightweight>
</definition>
```

And here is my code in test.py:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse('truncated.xml')
print(tree.find('definition/scm/userRemoteConfigs/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/url'))
tree.find('definition/scm/userRemoteConfigs/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/url').text = '<replacement text>'
```

Output:

```
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    tree.find('definition/scm/userRemoteConfigs/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/url').text = '<replacement text>'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build the tree the context is already `definition`. Try taking `definition/` off the front of your xpath...

```
tree.find('scm/userRemoteConfigs/hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig/url')
```